# This inventor was aware of prior art

Tags: prior-art

In reference to the patent: [US20150047576](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150047576)

This "inventor"  filed an a patent application after being notified of an near exact product already on market and in many publications. We have used a product called SleekEZ that states "patent pending", and we told the owner of Equigroomer about this BEFORE she filed as an "inventor". Her product does not look any different and says to do exactly the same thing. Is that legal?

Answer (score 1):

The applicant filed an Oath or Declaration on October 31, 2014 (see [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)) which states:

> The above-identified application was made or authorized to be made by me.
>
> I believe that I am the original inventor or an original joint inventor of a claimed invention in the application.
>
> I hereby acknowledge that any willful false statement made in this declaration is punishable under [18 U.S.C. 1001](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1001) by fine or imprisonment of not more than five (5) years, or both.

At first glance it does look too similar. Whether it is legal or not you should inform SleekEZ of this issue and suggest them at least to submit prior art documents via [Third-Party Preissuance Submissions](http://www.uspto.gov/patent/initiatives/third-party-preissuance-submissions).